# Syntax error in mysql, using create funtion

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create funtion tra (g_name varchar(10)) 
returns int 
begin   
  declare gpa int;   
  set gpa = 0;   
  gpa = case  
  when g_name = 'A+' THEN 5  
  when g_name = 'B+' THEN 4   ELSE 3
  END CASE;   
  RETURN gpa; end;//
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'funtion tra (g_name varchar(10)) returns int begin   declare gpa int;   set gpa ' at line 1

what is error in declare?

Comment: `function`, not `funtion`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the obvious typo on `funtion`, you are not using the `case` statement correctly. As opposed to the `case` expression, that is typically used within a query and returns a value, the `case` statement is a flow-control structure. Each branch should contain a statement, or a list of statement.

The correct syntax would be:

```
create function tra (g_name varchar(10)) 
returns int 
begin   
    declare gpa int;  

    case  
      when g_name = 'a+' then set gpa = 5;  
      when g_name = 'b+' then set gpa = 4;   
      else set gpa = 3;
    end case;   
    
    return gpa; 
end;
//
```

Comment: Thanks. but i has a one more question. after i made a function tra, i use the function like select tra (A+) but error occured.                                                                              
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near tra (A+)' at line 1

Comment: @김한규: `select tra('A+')`. The string needs single quotes.